# Accessing expando model properties

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a salary model which will handle salary of employees in multiple companies or rather I would say multiple work locations of the same company. So when I add salary components, I chose the model to be Expando, since each company may have country specific components according to their salary structure. These salary components are calculated when the payroll is run.
The problem is, I may need to display it somewhere, may be in the employee profile. How do I do it? For example,

> A in company ABC India will have
>
> > basic : 6600
> >
> > DA : 1250
>
> B in company ABC UK will have
>
> > HRA : 1500
> >
> > Special Allowance : 3000

Since these props are generated runtime according to the respective companies, how do I access them? I cannot write salary.basic for an employee in UK. I hope you understand my issue.

Comment: Are you referring to the Expando class in Google App Engine?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: you can always access properties with getattr.  ie `getattr(salary,'basic')`

Comment: I wont know which properties exist for the instance right. I can access salary.basic iff i know that basic exists right

Answer (score -1):

As Tim suggested, you can test if a attribute exists by doing:

```
basic_salary = getattr(salary, 'basic', False)
```

This way, basic_salary will be the value of `basic` if `salary` has this attribute, `False` otherwise.

Alternatively, you can get a list of properties an instance has by:

```
attributes = salary._properties.keys()
```

Though you are accessing what's meant to be a private part of the class, you can still access it (be careful to keep an eye on changes to the class that may break this kind of access). With this list, you can test if `basic` is in `salary` by:

```
has_basic = 'basic' in attributes
```